# Bluetooth headset works fine in HSP/HFP but one side is NOT working in A2DP Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: 19.10, a2dp

Hi everybody,

I'm new to Ubuntu. I'm using Ubuntu 19.10. I have a Bluetooth headset that has HSP/HFP and A2DP modes. I only was using A2DP and everything was fine. However, last week, I had to switch to HSP/HFP to be able to use my microphone for skype calls. Since then, my HSP/HFP works fine, but when I switch to A2DP, I can only hear sound from the left side. The right side is absolutely silent. I tried different soundtracks and the test in sound settings.

There is no problem with the headset because both sides are working in HSP/HFP, and also I tried other devices with my headset, and both sides are fine.

I need both HSP/HFP and A2DP. I've tried unpairing and pairing again, and restarting but that didn't work. 
How can I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I had the same problem
What worked for me, opening the settings -> audio

1. set A2DP for headpones
2. change the output device to another device, then switch it pack to the headphone
3. set balance in the middle (of left and right)

What I recognized, the balance (left/right) was on the left hand side. Before performing the steps above, changing the balance didn't change anything.
But after the steps above, everything worked fine.
Have a look on the image link below:

[image: Link to screenshot of my audio settings, in German]

Comment: Same issue for me on Ubuntu 20.04 with Bluetooth Headphones. For some reason all of a sudden the Balance was set all the way to the right.

Comment: I love you right now.

Comment: Working on Zorin 16.1 based on Ubuntu 20.04